# c++ : When is a declared variable is initialized without assigning it to any value?

Tags: c++

if I compile the code bellow as commenting out the line 13, I'm having a warning message that it says `warning: 'test.Test::x' is used uninitialized in this function` but if i compile it with the line 13, the compiler isn't warn that Test::x is uninitialized.

And my question is:

when I call line 7 in line 13 why the compiler didn't warn me about uninitialized variable x, if the x is initialized already when is that?

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    int x;
    void printX(){ std::cout << x << std::endl; } // ----------------line 7
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    // test.printX(); // --------------------------------------------line 13
    std::cout << test.x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which specific compiler?

Comment: i'm using g++ compiler

Comment: my compiler version is 5.1.0 and I'm compiling as follows `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o test test.cpp`

Comment: Interesting finding indeed. https://godbolt.org/z/y0uDXi Even more interesting fact is that the warning depends on optimization level: `-O0` (default) issues no warning, any higher (i.e. `-O1`) does warn. I'd expect this to be other way round. Not even adding `const` specifier to function `printX` helps with optimization disabled. Possibly someone with greater knowledge about compilers will be able to help, my answer would be speculations only.

Comment: You may be assuming that since the compiler didn't complain there isn't a problem. The question title seems to imply you assume `x` must be initialized because you didn't get a warning. This is an entirely incorrect assumption in c++. Compiling successfully does not mean you do not have errors. The compiler doesn't have to (and usually can't) detect and report all types of errors.

Comment: FWIW you should note that the compiler is not required to tell you you didn't initialize `x`.  That is more of a job for a static analysis tool (which the compiler only does so much of).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen at higher optimization levels the compiler does more analysis of the code to work out which optimizations are possible, so that makes it notice the uninitialized use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't initialize, it is uninitialized. Compilers make their best effort to help you to point out your bugs but not always possible and you cannot rely on those. If you use a latest version of the compiler, you get better warnings.

> if the x is initialized already when is that?

No, x is not initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is really confusing.  Not exactly sure what you're asking.

At any rate, raw data types are not initialized unless you do so explicitly.  Those and PODs.  Just initialize all of your data members.